# Amazon Data Pipeline Failing - Premature End of Content-Length Delimited Body

Tags: java, python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark

I've been running a spark job on Amazon Data Pipeline for months with no problem. On Friday, this error cropped up and now I'm unable to run the job. I've checked and tried to run prior dates data that previous succeeded, and they now fail. In that sense I've ruled out the data itself.

> at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited
> message body (expected: 677054400; received: 16384 at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.invokeListeners(TaskContextImpl.scala:138) at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.markTaskCompleted(TaskContextImpl.scala:116) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408) at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ... 1 more 21/01/08 05:59:34 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook

I'm seeing people online talk about java version, but this is a spark job on ADP. I don't specify the java version. How could I do that?